# MongoDB regexMatch not matching exact string

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have dataset like this:

```
 {
    country: "NO",
    population: 200,
    color: "blue",
    "Manager": "['Jim Brown']"
  },
  {
    country: "AE",
    population: 200,
    color: "red",
    "Manager": "['Jim', 'Arnold']"
  },
  {
    country: "AE",
    population: 200,
    color: "green",
    "Manager": "['Jim Brown', 'Sam']"
  },
```

I am trying to filter only the values that have Manager equal to `Jim`. So the result should only contain list that have exact matching string. In this case should only return list with `Jim` but not `Jim Brown`.
I tried using regexMatch:

```
         {
            "$regexMatch": {
              "input": "Manager",
              "regex": "/^Jim$/",
              
            }
          }
```

However it is not working.
Here is my playground with minimal reproducible example:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/kU2tH1YjO1F

Comment: Replace `"/^Jim$/"` with `'Jim'`? With `^` and `$` it matches the value from start to end, which all your data starts with `['` and ends with `']` with never be matched.

Comment: Kinda weird that `"Manager"` looks like an array, but it's a string, rather than having an array of strings.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I know but thats the data I am working with

Comment: @YongShun but when you check the results in the playground, when I replace it with `Jim` then I also get `Jim Brown` which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @AlexT Understood ... been there.

Comment: @AlexT I think what @YongShun meant was to use `"regex": "'Jim'"`, like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D3f48pcUb7V).